# VC++: Backgroundworker is not stopping

Tags: visual-c++, backgroundworker

I have a backgroundworker that is checking the serial port communication, but I want to stop it when the user clicks in the close serial port button. 
The code of the background worker:

```
private: System::Void  backgroundWorker1_DoWork(System::Object^  sender, System::ComponentModel::DoWorkEventArgs^  e) {
    while (true)
    {
        try {
            String^ tempVal = Arduino->ReadLine();
            this->SetText(tempVal); 
            Arduino->DiscardInBuffer();
            if (this->backgroundWorker1->CancellationPending) {
                e->Cancel = true;
                this->Arduino->Close();
                this->pictureAClose->Visible = false;
                return;
            }
        }
        catch (TimeoutException^) {
        }
    }
}
```

And the close port button:

```
private: System::Void pictureAClose_Click(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e) {
    this->backgroundWorker1->CancelAsync();     
}
```

Right now it does nothing when you click in the close port button.

Comment: Are you sure `Arduino->ReadLine();` isn't blocking?

Answer (score 0):

Agree with Johnny Mopp.  The ReadLine() is most likely blocking, which prevents the method from getting to the `if (this->backgroundWorker1->CancellationPending)` clause.  So cancelling the task doesn't cause that call to exit.

It looks like `Arduino` has a `Close()` method. If "Arduino" is designed correctly, then calling `Close()` should cause a blocking `ReadLine()` call to exit with exception (`ObjectDisposed` or something similar).  So change Click handler to something like this:

```
System::Void pictureAClose_Click(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e)
{
    this->backgroundWorker1->CancelAsync();     
    Arduino->Close();
}
```

(Actually, I'd put a `try/catch` around that `Close()` call just in case).

Note that you'll also need to add a more generic `Exception ^` clause to the worker thread method's `try/catch` block to catch other exceptions besides the Timeout.

I noticed something else that can cause you problems.  Inside your thread method, you have the following:

```
this->SetText(tempVal);
```

This might throw a wobbly (exception) because it's not doing this within the main Form's thread context.  You'll have to do an `Invoke` to execute this line of code in a synchronous context.

Also, based on your syntax, this can also be tagged under "c++-cli"